# function returns a promise reject when resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `angularjs` controller and factory.

So my purpose is to manage all the message errors depending of the promise result. That means to receive in the controller a reject after checking some bad values in the resolve factory function.

I'm trying this way but it doesn't work:

**factory.js**

```
var mediaRecent;
function getMediaByUserName(user) {
  return $http.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + user + '/media')
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.data.items.length === 0) {
        // I want here to cause a reject in the controller function
        return new Error('This user is not public');
      }
      mediaRecent = response.data.items;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      return new Error('There was a problem looking to that user');
    });
}
```

**controller.js**

```
instagramFactory.getMediaByUserName(vm.name)
  .then(function () {
    $state.go('instagramMediaRecent');
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    vm.error = error.message;
  });
```

Comment: Try throwing the error instead of returning it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mediaRecent;
function getMediaByUserName(user) {
  return $http.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + user + '/media')
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.data.items.length === 0) {
        // go to catch() from here
        return $q.reject(new Error('This user is not public'));
      }
      mediaRecent = response.data.items;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      return new Error('There was a problem looking to that user');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you called promise twice. So you can call it only in Controller or Factory.

**Simple way**

Factory:

```
function getMediaByUserName(user) {
  return $http.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + user + '/media');
}
```

Controller:

```
instagramFactory.getMediaByUserName(vm.name)
  .then(function () {
    if (response.data.items.length === 0) {
      // I want here to cause a reject in the controller function
      return new Error('This user is not public');
    }
    var mediaRecent = response.data.items;
    $state.go('instagramMediaRecent');
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    vm.error = new Error('There was a problem looking to that user');
  });
```